# Sum Current Month + 2 AND Next Month + 1 and Month After that

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a metric I need to replicate in DAX for PowerBI and I am not quite sure how to do it.

The basics are this:

Fact Table: Opportunity

Dimensions: Created Date, Closed Date

The metric goes like this, I will just give an example, because I really dont know how to explain it.

SUM OF:

Created in FEB and Closed Date in FEB, MAR, APR

Created in MAR and Closed Date in MAR, APR

Created in APR and Closed in APR

This would happen for each month in the table/matrix.

Seems like I would need some variables something like

Measure =

VAR Month1 = SUM(ClosedOpps) where ClosedDate between CurrentMonth and CurrentMonth + 2

VAR Month2 = SUM(CLosedOpps) where ClosedDate betwwen CurrentMonth + 1 and CurrentMonth + 2

VAR Month3 = SUM(ClosedOpps) where ClosedDate = CurrentMonth + 2

Return Month1 + Month2 + Month3

My understanding is, the Closed Date filter would be the Table/Matrix Visual when I drag the column MonthYear into the visual

EDIT:

Here is a simplified replica of what they are doing in Excel
[image: Report Sample]

So The data on the left is the fact table.  You can see when the Opps are created, when they are closed.  I added in the Created MonthYear and the Closed MonthYear.  The Pivot is what they have now in Excel.  Dates across the top (Columns) are Created YearMonth, Dates for the Rows are Closed YearMonth.

I need to be able to SUM the numbers inside the of I3:K5 which total 5500 in the example.

UPDATE:

So I have added in a suggested Date Dimension table, Duplicated it (One for Open Date, one for Closed Date) I added a column DateDIM_KEY to each which is just a numerical index.  The fact table has these keys, and they are loaded off of the same date range (2013 to 2030).  The column ActualValue in the fact table is the column we would SUM.

[image]

Here is the updated Fact table sample. I pulled the DateDIM_KEY values directly from the date dimension for those dates.
[image]

Comment: Could you provide a sample of data so we wouldn't guess?

Comment: See updated post with screen shot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a good date dimension. And you need to have it roleplaying for OpenDate and CloseDate. There are many good date dimensions out there. I like [mine](https://github.com/baldiniunlimited/daxdates).

Assuming that you're putting 'OpenDate'[Month] on an axis label.

```
Opportunity Value = SUM ( 'Opportunity'[Value] )
```

```
MyMeasure iterator =
// start of the month on the current row of a pivot/axis label of a chart
VAR CurrentMonthStart = MIN ( 'OpenDate'[Date] )
// End of the month 2 months out
VAR ThreeMonthsOutEnd = EOMONTH ( CurrentMonthStart, 2 )
// This represents one row per month. You could also use a MonthAndYear type field.
// We will walk through the three open months we care about, and in each will sum
// the value for the opportunities opened in that month, with additional filters.
VAR NextThreeOpenMonths =
  CALCULATETABLE (
    VALUES ( 'OpenDate'[MonthIndex] ),
    ALL ( 'OpenDate' ),
    DATESBETWEEN ( 'OpenDate'[Date], CurrentMonthStart, ThreeMonthsOutEnd )
  )
RETURN
  // Iterate each OpenMonth
  SUMX (
    NextThreeOpenMonths,
    // On each step of the iteration, grab the start of the currently iterated month
    VAR IterMonthStart = CALCULATE ( MIN ( 'OpenDate'[Date] ) )
    RETURN
      CALCULATE (
        [Opportunity Value],
        // There is date context from visuals we want to ignore:
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'OpenDate', 'OpenDate'[MonthIndex] ),
        // filter CloseDate to be between the start of the currently iterated
        // open month and the originally calculated ThreeMonthsOutEnd. The latter
        // is static within the scope of the iteration.
        DATESBETWEEN ( 'CloseDate'[Date], IterMonthStart, ThreeMonthsOutEnd )
      )
  )
```

Also, while writing the previous iterative approach, I realized we could do the work in a single setfilter:

```
MyMeasure set =
// MonthIndex is in my date dimension - super useful for arithmetic on dates.
// Read the readme.
VAR C = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'OpenDate'[MonthIndex] ) // want a short name below
// Table literal syntax - two column table, where each parenthesized expression
// forms a row. If it were much more, I'd do something clever with generate, but
// six cases are easy to write by hand.
VAR MonthFilters = {
  (C, C),
  (C, C+1),
  (C, C+2),
  (C+1, C+1),
  (C+1, C+2),
  (C+2, C+2)
}
RETURN
  CALCULATE (
    [Opportunity Value],
    TREATAS ( MonthFilters, 'OpenDate'[MonthIndex], 'CloseDate'[MonthIndex] )
  )
```

I like the latter a lot better, but didn't think of it until after writing the iterative version, so I'm leaving both. Set-based should be better performing.

Edit: some screengrabs I forgot:

Here's the relationship diagram for roleplaying date dim:

[image: relationship diagram for roleplaying date dim]

And here's the visual in action with both measures:

[image: visual with both measures]

Comment: This looks good, will try to implement in my Report and see if this does the trick.

Comment: It will take some heavy modification.  My issue now is, we load from a Date Warehouse.  Our fact table has date keys as opposed to Date fields, those are in the Dimension table. Though for now I can bring in those columns and add them to the fact table.  This looks like a really nice date Dim table. You should make it available is SQL!

Comment: I've got a SQL version that needs a lot of cleanup. This would work fine with date keys. You can trivially derive or join a date key to the date dimension I shared. Once you have the keys, you can use the dimension as-is. You should not try to put the other dim columns into the fact

Comment: Fortunately, the DateDIM_KEY is just a numeric Index. so I added that to your DateDim, however I am not getting any values returned. I have only attempted to implement the set based one.  Will try the other.

Comment: Hmm well, I stripped it down to just my fact table, and your date dimension (one for Open, and one for Closed) but im not getting anything back.

I did modify the dimension by adding an Index column, starting with 1. The fact table has DateDIM_KEY's based on a calendar dimension that runs from 2013-2030, and I configured that as the start/end dates for each date dimension.  So Im not sure where I am going off the rails here.

Comment: Can you edit your original to indicate your relationships and visual layout (which fields from which tables), with updated sample data and new keys?

Comment: OK, added updated screen shots.  I reused the sample fact data and grabbed the key values for those dates from the Date Dimension table the are scripted from. Date dimension start date value is 1/1/2013 and runs through 2030.  the DateDIM key for 1/1/2013 is the value 1 and increments from there, by 1.

Comment: Im not sure exactly what I did, but I got a sample of it working and was able to verify the numbers.

Comment: I was able to implement this successfully. The set based solution did not work though. But that's ok.  Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: You might need an `ALL ( 'OpenDate' ), ALL ( 'CloseDate' )` in the `CALCULATE` in addition to the `TREATAS`, depending how your visuals are configured. Glad it's working, though.

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do here is to add a custom column (under edit querys) with the date diff per month. Now you can filter after the column `LeadTimeInMonth` for you scenarios. If you drag and drop your fields into the visual you can filter by this column.

```
Date.Month([ClosedDAte])-Date.Month([OpenDate])
```

[image]

I am not sure what you really want to evaluate but if you need need exactly `ClosedDate between CurrentMonth and CurrentMonth + 2` you can first evaluate the month from the `ClosedDate` then the month of today and filter after the result.

Comment: You'll need to update your differencing formula to cover multiple years. Imagine December, 2018 open and January, 2019 close. That's 1-12=-11. You could add 12 if negative to get back to a proper lead time in months. Or you could leverage an index column on months, or if you're sourcing from a database, you could use its date differencing functions. You could also mess about with getting a month out of an M duration type.